# CI Url Parameters not getting with _REQUEST Method

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, request, codeigniter-3

I've been using this project since last 8 months and it works absolute fine.my api calls looks like below

http://domainname.com/webservice/signinOrganization?vFirebaseDeviceToken=someToken&vPassword=123456&vUserEmail=provider@demo.com&type=signinOrganization //Just for demo purpose

And webservice code is look like this

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Webservice_model');

        $type = isset($_REQUEST['type']) ? trim($_REQUEST['type']) : '';
        
        if(empty($type)){
            $result['Action'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = 'Required parameter missing.';
            $result['errMsg'] = 'ERR_MISSING_TYPE';
            $result['REQUEST_PARAM'] = $_REQUEST;
            $result['REQUEST_PARAM_CI'] = $this->input->get();
            
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit;
        }
```

And Output is look like this
https://prnt.sc/vvhj9f

Since this code is working fine earlier and suddenly after changing domain name it stopped working.
if i using `$_REQUEST` method it returns me url instead of returning parameters.
where as `$this->input->get();` working perfectly.

but i cant use `$this->input->get();` as i've used `$REQUEST` method everywhere in my code as it was working earlier.

could you please let me find why this was happening.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/security.html#register-globals):

> During system initialization all global variables that are found to exist in the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` and `$_COOKIE` are unset.

So, I'll advise you use `$this->input->get()` or `$this->input->post()` instead.

Comment: thanks for this but i cant use as already this system is working earlier but not now after changing domain name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just updated it like this:

```php
$something = isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL;
```

For [Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html)

If you still get the same error you should remove that code from `_construct` method and pass it into Post API.